# Updating button in android

Tags: java, android

I am creating an address Book app but I have a problem. When I am trying to set text to the button it doesn't update on the screen.
Here is a part of my main layout:

```
   public void call(View v){

setContentView(R.layout.call);

Numbers num = new Numbers(cont);
 final Names names = new Names(cont);
   button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.name1);

   if(num.getNumber("1").isEmpty()) {
       button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               setContentView(R.layout.activity_aseta_numero);
               Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.readyButton);


               button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                       EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Number);

                       Numbers j = new Numbers(cont);
                       j.setNumber(text.getText().toString(), "1");

                       EditText tex = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NameField);

                       names.adName(tex.getText().toString(), "1");


                       button.setText(names.getNimi("1") + "moi");

                       setContentView(R.layout.call);
                       System.out.println(button.getText());


                   }
               });

           }
       });
   }else {




   }
```

Here is my name class:

```
public class Names extends Activity{

SharedPreferences pres;
Button Nappi;
Context context;
public Names(Context mcontext){

 context = mcontext;
pres = context.getSharedPreferences("1",0);
}
public void adName(String name, String place){


    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pres.edit();
    editor.putString(name,place);
    editor.commit();
    System.out.println(pres.getString("1", ""));
}

public String getName(String place){

    return pres.getString(place,"");

}

}
```

and here is my setnumber XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="oo.seniorlauncher.com.o_seniorlauncher.setnumber">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Syötä"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:textSize="50dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="numero"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:width="250dp"
    android:textSize="50dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="ja nimi"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textSize="50dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/NameField"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Nimi" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/Number"
    android:layout_below="@+id/NameField"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:text="Numero"
    android:phoneNumber="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Valmis"
    android:id="@+id/readyButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Number"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textSize="75dp" />
```

and here is the call layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="oo.seniorlauncher.com.o_seniorlauncher.soita1">


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/name1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/name2"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/name1"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/name1"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/name3"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/name4"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/name3"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/name3" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/name5"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/name6"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/name5"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/name5" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Home"
    android:id="@+id/home1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/name6"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/name6"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:textSize="80dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Show all numbers"
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name5"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/home1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

recreate() and .invalide didn't help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot see a `name1` entry in your xml file. `findViewById(R.id.name1);` should throw an error.

Comment: Are you sure the onClick method of button1 is called ?

Comment: @Jordi can you elaborate on that? I think that Uma Kanth is right.

Comment: Well in fact, you are changing the whole layout with this line setContentView(R.layout.call);
So it's normal that your button doesn't change as it gets wiped out of your screen.

Comment: Never seen a messy onCreate like this ever before. As @Gordak pointed out, you are changing your layout by calling setContentView(R.layout.call); after setting text to button, so button will be recreated again on screen and not updated with your text.

Comment: sorry forgot one xml layout